# Glassfish, EJB Load balancing

Tags: glassfish, ejb, cluster-computing, load-balancing

I'm having a problem with ejb load balancing inside glassfish 3 cluster.

I have one ear project witch contains EJB module and WEB module. All my EJB's are stateless and remote in EJB module. In WEB module I have one servlet which suppose to lookup for ejb and print on which instance in cluster he get ejb.

I'm calling EJB from servlet like this:

`Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("com.sun.appserv.iiop.endpoints", "10.8.10.202:23700,10.8.10.203:23700,10.8.10.204:23700,10.8.10.205:23700");
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();`

EJBRemote ejb = (EJBRemote) ic.lookup("java:global/app-name-ear/app-ejbs/EJB!com.tt.EJBRemote");

Problem is that my request always ends up on first instance of 4 possible.

How I can achieve load balancing in my case? Do I need stand alone client (web-app in separate project)? How glassfish cluster knows that there are another instances where my servlet can lookup for EJB?

Comment: Try to enable [Per-Request Load Balancig](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24934/rmi-iiop.htm#gknpv), and let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi, Gabriel. Thanks for response. I have try to enable PRLB but I've got the same situation. Every request ends up on same instance.

Comment: It seems to be that there is a WS [bug](https://www.java.net//forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/glassfish-312-rmi-iiop-request-load-balancing-broken-312). Possible [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16715) report.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. I didn't know about this bug. Is it a good idea to implement my own load balancer (round robin)? Any hint or example is welcome.

Comment: I think still there is a chance. Try to share the same EJB reference among all request. I mean, the first request will lookup the Stub and store it in Session, the next ones instead of lookup a new stub will use the one previously polled; this way the stub's state will be maintained among requests. (It's hard to believe that proxy load balancing doesn't work in WS.)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you don't have enough load.  and the way you look up EJBs is odd.

To look up remote EJB, rather than the properties in a servlet. but the CORBA / IIOP URL in the JNDI resources of the server.   (in the admin console)

When you load balance, with IIOP each lookup binds to one instance and only switches to another instance for failover.

essentially you don't have enough load on the system to trigger the other instances of the EJB.  Perhaps reduce the pool size to one to simulate high load.